# Transfer files from Google Drive to Cluster account

Tags: perl, google-drive-api

The google API is confusing me. I have no idea how to approach this problem.

I have 62GB of data on a google drive account. I want it transferred to my server cluster account. How can I do this without downloading the data to my local device and uploading it to a server; cut out the middle man?

I know perl but the perl module for google drive api is ambiguous at best.

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive server cannot actively upload file to your server. Your server should have authorized Drive API to download from Google Drive. To rephrase, you can't "upload" from Drive to remote server. You should "download" from Drive to remote server.

To do this, you need to authenticate your web application. Then, you can select file and retrieve fileId of the file you want to download to remote server. Then, you send this fileId to your remote server with, for example, simple HTTP request. Your server will then trigger [**download of the file**](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads?hl=en) from Drive.